# How to make ajax faster and a ajax loaded Reply text field like on orkut

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

HEllo,

I have a site where I want to introduce reply user functionality. How to make an ajax loaded reply text field like a popup? currently, i m using a text field which takes hell lot of time on clicking reply. Is there any method to make it faster?

My ajax call is :

```
$("#replyMe").click(function(){


 $().ajaxStart($.blockUI);
 $.ajax({


  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo $html->url('/askmeouts/sent/'.$to['Profile']['id'])?>",

  success: function(msg){



   $('.show').html(msg);

   }
});
```

Comment: You have to follow steps described here.. http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/the-perfect-jquery-ajax-request/ It will solve your problem as it solved my problem already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to make the server respond faster.

Your on-reply code is trivial, so the delay doesn't come from there. To verify that, you can use something like firebug and check the timing of the request and the response or maybe even look at your web server's log to see how long it took it.